# Issues debugging Moles

Tags: debugging, pex-and-moles, moles

I’m using visual studio 2008 and moles version 0.93. Everything works well except when I try to debug any test that uses a Moled type. The test skips all my breakpoints. And I get the following message in the output window:

Unable to attach. Check for one of the following.

1. The application you are trying to debug uses a version of the Microsoft .NET Framework that is not supported by the debugger.
2. The debugger has made an incorrect assumption about the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use.
3. The Microsoft .NET Framework version specified by you for debugging is incorrect

Please see the Visual Studio .NET debugger documentation for correctly specifying the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use for debugging.

If I try debbuger.Break () I get a message: "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed."

I’m in a crunch right now chasing an issue with one our main components and it has been a pain (like I need novocaine) trying to figure anything out without being able to step through the code.

I want to take advantage of mole's "smooth debugging experience".  However, I can't seem to get the debugger to attach at all.

Thanks,

Bzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the solution to this issue here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/91c08bf4-3260-458c-a221-91f030a75499

Comment: I hate to answer my own question but I kind of dug around and find the answer.  Sorry.

Comment: that's perfectly fine to do that. Saves someone else the time of answering a question that you've already gotten an answer to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I moved a project from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2008.  Here's what I did to fix it.

Close Visual Studio.  Navigate to the Debug/bin location.  Delete the following files:

- *.vshost.exe
- *.vshost.exe.config
- *.vshost.exe.manifest

Open the solution.  Goto the project Settings.  Under the Application Target Framework, select a framework lower than the one you are working with (you'll set it back later). Visual Studio will close and re-open your project automatically.  Then set the Target Framework back to the original version you were working with.  Rebuild all, and debugging will work properly.